# Why is my debug category not logging?

Tags: java, log4j

This is my properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DATEDFILE, CONSOLE, DEBUG

### direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.DATEDFILE=biz.minaret.log4j.DatedFileAppender
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.Prefix=arendeprocess.
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.Suffix=.log
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.Directory=//localhost/WebsphereLog/PandoraArendeWeb/
```

I think it should make the category DEBUG log, why doesn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DATEDFILE, CONSOLE, DEBUG

You are explicitly setting the minimum level of logging to INFO, followed by the list of appenders where the log statement should be logged. So, the mention of `DEBUG` in that list means you are going to define an appender whose name is `DEBUG` and it doesn't refer to `DEBUG` log level, AFAIU.

Comment: Aha, so I should write it this way: `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, DATEDFILE, CONSOLE`

Comment: Right, the first argument is the level, whatever follows are the names of the appenders.

Comment: Or, if you want different levels for different loggers, use
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DATEDFILE
log4j.logger.myLoggerName=DEBUG